# How to get message properties in ActiveMQ Artemis broker queue via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code that gets the property name `_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE`, but I don't understand how I can get all the headers.

```java
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
Enumeration propertyNames = messages.get(0).getPropertyNames();
while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    if (propertyNames.nextElement().equals("_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE")) {
        isLarge = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already looping through all of the property names and looking for a property named `_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE`. All you need to do is change the code so it gets the property value and does something with it, e.g.:

```java
boolean isLarge = false;
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
Enumeration propertyNames = messages.get(0).getPropertyNames();
while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String propertyName = propertyNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Property name: " + propertyName + "; property value: " + messages.get(0).getObjectProperty(propertyName));
    if (propertyName.equals("_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE")) {
        isLarge = true;
    }
}
```